# scikit-image: mean filter changes dtype

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I'm using the [mean filter](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html#skimage.filters.rank.mean) from sci-kit image. However, it seems to change the `dtype` of floating-point images to `uint8`, which leads to a problem when passing that again to other filter functions.

As an illustration, consider the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import filters
from skimage.morphology import square

def mean_filter(img):
    selem = square(3)
    print(img.dtype)
    print(img.max(), img.min())
    fi =  filters.rank.mean(img, selem=selem)
    print(fi.dtype)
    print(fi.max(), fi.min())
    return fi

arr = np.array([[.1, .2, .3], 
                [.4, .5, .6],
                [.7, .8, .9]], dtype='float64')
m = mean_filter(arr)
```

Gives the following output.

```
float64
0.9 0.1
uint8
178 76
```

However, according to the documentation the return type should be the same as the input type. What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scikit-image's `rank` filters are only defined for `uint8` and `uint16` data types. That is why it is making the conversion to `uint8`, the type in which you get the result. E.g. [documentation rank.mean](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html#skimage.filters.rank.mean), where it says:

> image : 2-D array (uint8, uint16)

So, if you input an `uint8` or an `uint16`, skimage will preserve that data type in the result. Otherwise, it is going to try to convert your image to one of those under the hood.

What you can do, instead, is use `scipy`:

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter
>>> size = 3
>>> result = uniform_filter(arr, size)
```

Or if you fancy, create your own filter:

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d
>>> size = 3
>>> kernel = np.ones(size, arr.dtype) / size
>>> result = convolve1d(convolve1d(arr, kernel, axis=0), kernel, axis=1)
```

Note: The above is called a [separable convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter). It works by convolving the image with two 1-dimensional filters, first in the `y` axis and then over the `x` axis (order does not matter). Despite it looking ugly (as you have to convolve an image twice), when your kernel (filter) is separable, running two 1-dimensional convolutions is orders of magnitude faster than running a single 2D convolution. Scipy's `uniform_filter` does this behind scenes. It calls once per axis to `uniform_filter1d`.